# Cannot ssh into server using host:port syntax

Tags: ssh

This one works:

```bsh
ssh root@host -p port
```

But this one does not, returning `Name or service not known`:

```bsh
ssh root@host:port
```

The help prints

```bsh
usage: ssh
...
           [-i identity_file] [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address]
...
```

Why the second syntax does not work for me?

Comment: As you see, the second format is only for the `-J` option. See `man ssh` for more details.

Comment: Crazy me miss that :) @FedonKadifeli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you wanted is only for the `-J` option and not for the *destination* option.

From the man page:

```
ssh connects and logs into the specified destination,
which may be specified as either [user@]hostname
or a URI of the form ssh://[user@]hostname[:port].
```